# Windows 7 with Ubuntu on Dell studio 15

Tags: 10.10

Dell studio 15. C: 40gb primary (win7), 130gb on D: and E: How to go dual boot with Ubuntu and what about drivers?If my dell driver cd will work???

Comment: No. Your drivers on the cd will not work because they are intended for windows. Linux is pretty good with hardware detection, so you can boot from a live DVD or USB stick and have a look around and test what is working. Then you can search for solutions if something specific is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Driver CD generally gives only Windows drivers.
You can download drivers from net.

Else most of the commonly used drivers work with your hardware. Ubuntu is clever enough to make them work. so don't worry.
You can go for dual boot.
Just be careful when giving partitions for installation.

Create USB bootable drive of Ubuntu and start setup from it.

Hope this helps.